# Find upper bound index in sorted vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector like the following in Matlab.

```
 Columns 1 through 4

   0.160000000000000   0.208000000000000   0.244000000000000   0.268000000000000

  Column 5

   0.280000000000000
```

And I want to find the upper bound index of the following value:

```
0.16230400000000
```

I know this value is between the 1° and 2° indices, but I want to find the upper bound which in this case is index 2, even when the closest value is at index 1. How do I get that in Matlab without a loop?

I found the following method to find the closest value but I need always the upper bound.

```
[c ind] = min(abs(probCum-codComp));
```

Comment: do you have an error there? the value you search for is not greater, but less than vector(1).

Comment: Are you saying that 0.106230400000000 is between 0.160000000000000 and 0.208000000000000 ?!

Comment: Sorry I added an extra zero check my question again pelase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array is sorted in an ascending fashion, the find command is especially powerful:

```
find (a>0.162,1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the index of the upper bound by counting how many entries are smaller than the value of interest increased by one:

```
id = sum(value < data)+1;
```

Note that, if all elements are smaller than the value of interest, `data(id)` will return an error because `id` is larger than the size of `data`.

Comment: You need a +1 there I think, but otherwise nice.

Comment: @angainor: Yes, already noted. The edit was just underway when your comment came in. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second output from `min` to get the indices to the "proper" index:

```
[~,index] = min(abs(data-value));
```

then check if the lower or upper was taken, and adjust `index` accordingly:

```
if value > data(index)  
    index = min(length(data), index+1); end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract the value you search for from the vector and observe the sign

```
V =  [0.1600    0.2080    0.2440    0.2680    0.2800];
v =  0.162304;
V-v
ans =

-0.0023    0.0457    0.0817    0.1057    0.1177
```

Now you can `find` the first non-negative entry in this vector - this is your upper bound

```
find(V-v>=0, 1, 'first')
ans =

 2
```

You can also change the inequality in the expression above to suite your needs.