# Matlab - obtaining indices for the elements of a vector which pass a certain sum limit

Tags: matlab

I have a vector which is normalize(i.e. the sum of its elements is `1`) and they are ordered descending(i.e. `[0.5 0.4 0.09 0.01]`).

Is there a way of obtaining the indices of the first elements who's sum is just bellow a certain threshold?

For example, in my case, for a threshold of `0.6` I would obtain `1`, the index(w.r.t. to Matlab way of indexing vector elements) of `0.5`. For a threshold of `0.91` I would obtain `[1 2]`, the indices of `[0.5 0.4]`, and so on.

I know that I can do this with a loop through the vector but given the fact that I am using Matlab, I thought asking whether I can do this with just a single command line or max 2, thus increasing the computational speed of my code.

Comment: Use cumsum on your vector and look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692586/find-upper-bound-index-in-sorted-vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cumsum` function computes the cumulative sum of a vector's elements. doing this, and then finding the index for which the threshold turns smaller than the cumulative sum will give you your answer:

```
V = [0.5 0.4 0.09 0.01]

t = 0.6;

index = find(t < cumsum(V), 1)-1
```

Note that if `index = 0`, the condition does not hold even for the first element.

If you insist on getting a vector of elements that qualify, you can simply define a range with this:

```
indices = 1 : (find(t<cumsum(V),1)-1)
```

In this case, the `indices` vector is empty in case the first element doesn't qualify.

Comment: For selecting the result vector, `find` is unnecessary and you can use logical indexing: `result = V(cumsum(V)<t)`.